# How to clear saved settings of video card

Tags: drivers, video, graphics-card, amd-radeon

When I install video card driver, it changes the windows 10 resolution dimension automatically or probably loads previous saved setting and in this setting my monitor shows `out of range` error. To fix this I remove video card and power on with integrated video card then turn on `safe mode` option in `msconfig` window then turn off the machine, then plug in the video card again and turn on the machine again. In this step I change video card driver to `Microsoft basic display adapter` and reboot the system to normal mod. every thing is fine but when I want to install the video card original driver the problem happens again!! i.e. my monitor shows `out of range` error.

It seems that some settings has been saved somewhere in driver but I don't know where.

How to get ride of this error?

Note that I've changed my 24" monitor to 17" one and It was fine in my previous 24" monitor.

```
OS: Win 10 
OS build: 19042.1466
Version: 20H2
CPU: Core i3-3220
GPU: AMD Radeon 7000
```

Comment: I'm curious what monitor you have the Windows has problems detecting and setting the default resolution for

Comment: LG 17". But Integrated Intel HD graphic is fine I think because of it has no saved setting.

Comment: There is a good chance your experiencing a hardware sign. The hardware required for the basic adapter driver is far different then the Radeon drivers from AMD. GPU can work, specifically output a display, but when tasked actually cause problems or cause system crashes